# persist state after page refresh in React using local storage

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, persistence

What I would like to happen is when `displayBtn()` is clicked for the items in localStorage to display.

In `useEffect()` there is  `localStorage.setItem("localValue", JSON.stringify(myLeads))` MyLeads is an array which holds leads const `const [myLeads, setMyLeads] = useState([]);` myLeads state is changed when the `saveBtn()` is clicked `setMyLeads((prev) => [...prev, leadValue.inputVal]);`

In DevTools > Applications,  localStorage is being updated but when the page is refreshed localStorage is empty []. How do you make localStorage persist state after refresh? I came across this [article](https://joaoforja.com/blog/how-to-persist-state-after-a-page-refresh-in-react-using-local-storage/) and have applied the logic but it hasn't solved the issue. I know it is something I have done incorrectly.

````
import List from './components/List'
import { SaveBtn } from './components/Buttons';

function App() {
  const [myLeads, setMyLeads] = useState([]);
  const [leadValue, setLeadValue] = useState({
    inputVal: "",
  });

  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setLeadValue((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [name]: value,
      };
    });
  };

  const localStoredValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localValue")) ;

  const [localItems] = useState(localStoredValue || []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("localValue", JSON.stringify(myLeads));
  }, [myLeads]);

  const saveBtn = () => {
    setMyLeads((prev) => [...prev, leadValue.inputVal]);
    // setLocalItems((prevItems) => [...prevItems, leadValue.inputVal]);

    setDisplay(false);
  };

  const displayBtn = () => {
    setDisplay(true);    
  };


  const displayLocalItems = localItems.map((item) => {
    return <List key={item} val={item} />;
  });

  return (
    <main>
      <input
        name="inputVal"
        value={leadValue.inputVal}
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
      />

      <SaveBtn saveBtn={saveBtn} />

      <button onClick={displayBtn}>Display Leads</button>

      {display && <ul>{displayLocalItems}</ul>}
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;```
````

Comment: You've got a typo - change `saveBtn={saveBtn}` to `onClick={saveBtn}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've fallen into a classic React Hooks trap - because using `useState()` is so easy, you're actually overusing it.

If `localStorage` is your storage mechanism, then you don't need `useState()` for that AT ALL. You'll end up having a fight at some point between your two sources about what is "the right state".

All you need for your use-case is something to hold the text that feeds your controlled `input` component (I've called it `leadText`), and something to hold your `display` boolean:

```
  const [leadText, setLeadText] = useState('')
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false)
  const localStoredValues = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('localValue') || '[]')

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    setLeadText(value)
  }

  const saveBtn = () => {
    const updatedArray = [...localStoredValues, leadText]
    localStorage.setItem('localValue', JSON.stringify(updatedArray))
    setDisplay(false)
  }

  const displayBtn = () => {
    setDisplay(true)
  }

  const displayLocalItems = localStoredValues.map((item) => {
    return <li key={item}>{item}</li>
  })

  return (
    <main>
      <input name="inputVal" value={leadText} type="text" onChange={handleChange} required />

      <button onClick={saveBtn}> Save </button>

      <button onClick={displayBtn}>Display Leads</button>

      {display && <ul>{displayLocalItems}</ul>}
    </main>
  )
```